# Why does my NestJS app try to connect to localhost when it runs inside docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I have a NestJS project (monorepo) and now I'm trying to run all the apps as separate docker containers.

My docker-compose.yml seems like below:

```
version: '3.8'
services:  
  app-one:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/app-one/Dockerfile
    container_name: mono_app-one
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
  app-two:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/app-two/Dockerfile
    container_name: mono_app-two
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
```

The Dockerfiles seem like:

```
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 AS development
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=development
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --app-one
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm start --app-one"]
```

The app.module.ts files seem like:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: 'development.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mssql',
      host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
      port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 1433,
      username: process.env.USER,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [SomeEntity],
      synchronize: false,
      options: { encrypt: false },
    }),    
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And finaly development.env is:

```
PORT=1433
HOST=12.34.56.78
USER=admin
PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=MyDb
```

When I run **docker-compose up --build** images are created correctly, containers as well. But when the containers run, I see errors:

[image]

Even if I pass port, host, user, pass etc. directly (hardcoded) I see same errors. **The question is: Why? In this case I have to look at attempts to connect with 12.34.56.78.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConfigService` instead of `process.env` when initializing `TypeOrmModule`.

see following doc:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('HOST'),
    port: +configService.get<number>('PORT'),
    username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
    password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('DATABASE'),
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

Comment: Why is this way better? What will be changed?

Comment: Not better but this is how you used `ConfigService`. Please follow the documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration